# (jQuery.js error) uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#]

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am having trouble with a WP plugin. Users cannot upload an avatar or background, as well as view their profile from the profile section. Once the button is pushed to perform profile related actions they are redirected to the home page. Here is a bit of the code (functions receiving errors) and pictures of the console log errors errors.

some console log errors are because there are no pictures. I have deliberately removed profile and background photos. This problem happens with or without images.

```
/*! jQuery v1.12.4 | (c) jQuery Foundation | jquery.org/license */
!function(a,b){"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=a.document?b(a,!0)
function(a){if(!a.document){throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return b(a)}:b(a)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:this,
function(a,b){var c=[],d=a.document,e=c.slice,f=c.concat,g=c.push,h=c.indexOf,i={},j=i.toString,k=i.hasOwnProperty,l={},m="1.12.4",n=function(a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)},o=/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g,p=/^-ms-/,q=/-([\da-z])/gi,r=
function(a,b){return b.toUpperCase()};n.fn=n.prototype={jquery:m,constructor:n,selector:"",length:0,toArray:
```

I have performed the following Troubleshooting task:

1. uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin.
2. Adjusted all settings for redirects.
3. Checked Themes (not the theme).
4. Deleted everything and started from scratch.
5. Deactivated all other plugins (plugins not the problem).

[This is the Console log error for users attempting to change their background or avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAQpS.png)

[The 2nd picture is of the console log error when an individual tries to view their profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJfMa.png)

Comment: As a general rule, if you get an error thrown at you from the middle of jQuery, it's because you passed it something invalid. You should try using the "Pause on unhandled exceptions" features of Developer Tools, and check the call stack to see what led to the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[href=#]` is not a valid CSS selector.

In an attribute selector (the `[name=value]` syntax), the value MUST be surrounded by quotes UNLESS the value is a valid CSS identifier: starts with a letter, contains only letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores (in this case, quotes are optional)

Since `#` quite clearly fails the "valid CSS identifier", it must be quoted.

`[href='#']` will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to jQuery and have more experience in Java Script. If you would not mind helping me to implement this concept I would gladly appreciate it. Once again, thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: Basically, jQuery takes a CSS selector (with a few extensions, but it's recommended you use `.filter()` or similar methods if you want them). So long as what you pass it is a valid CSS selector, it'll work with jQuery.